# Preparation of di-phenyl ester from phenol

Tags: organic-chemistry

How to create di-phenyl ester from phenol in laboratory. What would be the steps. I am asking this question as it can not be done by Williamson ether synthesis.

Comment: This is a [homework](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/141/7448) question. We have a policy which states that ‎you should show your thoughts and/or efforts into solving the problem. It'll make us certain that ‎we aren't doing your homework for you. Otherwise, this question may get closed.‎ Please [edit] in your full reasoning or thoughts on this.

Comment: Does [this](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.iaea.org/inis/collection/NCLCollectionStore/_Public/36/095/36095257.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjl1aOP3oTZAhVFwI8KHa-mC6g4ChAWMAB6BAgTEAE&usg=AOvVaw3UxjfND-hF26IUIlHay1w7)  help

Comment: Do you mean diphenyl ether?

Comment: No sorry I want the preparation of di-phenyl ester (ph-o-ph)

Comment: PhOPh is Diphenyl Ether!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Diphenyl ethers have been prepared from condensation in melt phase of potassium phenoxide and aryl bromides in the presence of Copper and Copper(I) Chloride - J. Chem. Eng. Data, 1978, **23** (2), 185–186

US patent 4564712 A also describes a similar process